# Elisp programming: Jump to heading with a specific `Custom_ID` property value

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, search, org-properties

Within the same org buffer, how to jump to heading with a specific `Custom_ID` property value?
**Edit:**
I need an Elisp function that takes a string argument and jumps to the heading with a Custom_Id property's value equal to that string.
 *Sorry for not being clear from the start. I didn't anticipate that my project would require me to work specifically with Elisp programming*.

**Note about the accepted answer:**

- The [first answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77634/40390) , shows how to accomplish my request interactively.
- The [second answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77661/40390), shows how to accomplish my request by using Elisp

  Both answers should have been accepted, and the separation is due to my lack of consistency and clarity from the start.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modified question asks for a Lisp function to jump to the headline whose `CUSTOM_ID` property has the given value. The question is underspecified because there may be multiple headlines with a `CUSTOM_ID` property having that value.

The following solution assumes that you want to go to the first match, but can be modified fairly easily to do something else (which is left for you to figure out and implement).

The first function finds all the matches as a list and returns a list of positions, the positions of the headlines that match. That is completely general and can be used even if my assumption about the first match is inadequate.

The second function then checks that the list is non-empty and jumps to the position that is first on that list.

```el
(defun my/find-custom-id (value)
  (org-map-entries #'point (format "CUSTOM_ID=\"%s\"" value) 'file))

(defun my/goto-first-match (value)
  (interactive "sCUSTOM_ID value: ")
  (let ((poslist (my/find-custom-id value)))
    (if (> (length poslist) 0)
        (goto-char (nth 0 (my/find-custom-id value)))
      (message "No CUSTOM_ID with value %s" value))))
```

You could simplify the test of non-emptiness for `poslist` but I left it like this to make it more easily generalizable.

You can call it from Lisp like this: `(my/goto-first-match "foo")` or you can call it interactively like this: `M-x my/goto-first-match` and enter `foo` at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sparse tree search `C-c / p custom_id RET <value>`. See [Sparse Trees](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sparse-Trees.html) in the manual. The sparse tree is (mostly) folded, but top-level headlines that match are highlighted and lower-level headlines that match unfolded up to the headline (you can change the behavior, but I think I am describing the default behavior). So it is easy to find all the matching headlines. You can exit the sparse tree view with `C-c C-c`.

For example, if I have an Org mode file like this:

```org
* something
wild
* one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: foo
:END:

* something
wicked this way comes
* two
** two.one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: barfoo
:END:

* something
completely different
* three
** three.one
*** three.one.one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: foo
:END:

** three.two

*** three.two.one
```

and I do `C-c / p CUSTOM_ID RET foo`, I get this view:

[image: property search results]

The highlights (on the `one` headline and the `three.one.one` headline - note that the red rectangle is my cursor, it is not a highlight) indicate a match, so you can TAB on each one to open it and on the `PROPERTIES` drawer underneath to verify. Note that all other headlines (in particular the three `something` headlines) don't match and remain folded *and* un-highlighted. When you are done, exit the sparse tree view with `C-c C-c`.

`C-c /` can yield sparse trees based on different matching criteria: `p` for properties, `r` for regexps, `m` for matching tags and properties (see [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html) in the manual), and others.

For example, doing `C-c / r CUSTOM_ID RET` will find all `CUSTOM_ID` properties (as well as other places mentioning `CUSTOM_ID`: it just uses it the string `CUSTOM_ID` as a regexp). This is what that looks like on the example above:

[image: regexp search results]

`C-c / m` can do all sorts of searches but you need to practice: the matching language is somewhat peculiar. You'll probably have to reread the section I linked to above a few times.

Comment: As a new Emacs user , thank you for introducing me to Org-sparse-tree.
However, I am looking to satisfy my same request using Elisp programming. I need an Elisp function that takes a string argument and jumps to the heading with a Custom_Id property's value equal to that string.
Sorry for not being clear from the start. I didn't anticipate that my project would require me to work with Elisp programming.